# r sum several colmns by another column

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

I have a 39 column (with upward of 100000 rows) data frame whose last ten columns looks like that (The rest of the columns do not concern my question)

```
H3K27me3_gross_bin H3K4me3_gross_bin H3K4me1_gross_bin UtoP UtoM UPU UPP UPM UMU UMP UMM
cg00000029                  3                 3                 6    1    1   0   0   0   0   0   0
cg00000321                  6                 1                 5    1    0   0   1   0   0   0   0
cg00000363                  6                 1                 1    1    0   1   0   0   0   0   0
cg00000622                  1                 2                 1    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
cg00000714                  2                 5                 6    1    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
cg00000734                  2                 6                 2    0    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I want to create a matrix that will:

a) count the number of rows in which the value columns UPU, UPP or UPM is 1 by each of the first three columns (H3K27me3_gross_bin, H3K4me3_gross_bin, H3K4me1_gross_bin)
b) sum each row of the columns UPU, UPP, UPM by the first three columns

I came up with this incredibly cumbersome way of doing this:

```
UtoPFrac<-seq(6)
 UtoPTotEvents<-seq(6)
 for (j in 1:3){
  y<-df[,28+j]
  for (i in 1:3){
   UtoPFrac<-cbind(UtoPFrac,tapply(df[which(is.na(y)==FALSE),33+i],y[which(is.na(y)==FALSE)], function(x) length(which(x==1))))
}
}
UtoPFrac<-UtoPFrac[,2:10]
UtoPEvents<-cbind(rowSums(UtoPFrac[,1:3]),rowSums(UtoPFrac[,4:6]),rowSums(UtoPFrac[,7:9]))
```

I am certian there is a more elegent way of doing this, probably by using aggregate() or ddply(), but was unable to get this working.
I will apprciate any help doing this more efficenly

Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be better if you used `dput` and `head` to post your data.frame. It appears that you have 12 columns and 11 column names.

Comment: Unfortunately it is unclear what you wish to achieve. Can you please update your question with the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested:

```
  library(plyr)
  dpply(df,.(H3K27me3_gross_bin, H3K4me3_gross_bin, H3K4me1_gross_bin), summarize, UPUl=length(UPU[which(UPU==1)]),UPPl=length(UPP[which(UPP==1)]),UPMl=length(UPM[which(UPM==1)]), mysum=sum( UPU + UPP + UPM))
```

P.S. If you `dput` the data and provide the expected output, I will test the above code